# Know any good c++ support vector machine (SVM) libraries?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

Do you know of any good c++ svm libraries out there
I tried libsvm http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/ but so far I'm not flabbergasted.

I have also heard of **SVMLight** and **TinySVM**. Have you tried them ? Any new players ?

Thanks !

Comment: libsvm is great, though, and works really well.

Comment: Yeah, I have used it a little more and now I can say it works well enough for me, no need for anything fancier :)

Comment: LibSVM and SVMLight are well known mature libs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- [SVMTorch](http://bengio.abracadoudou.com/SVMTorch.html) (support vector machines for large-scale regression problems) implemented in the [torch](http://www.torch.ch/) machine learning library.
- [mySVM](http://www-ai.cs.uni-dortmund.de/SOFTWARE/MYSVM/index.html) - based on the optimization algorithm of [SVM-Light](http://svmlight.joachims.org/).

A comprehensive list of SVM libraries can be found [here](http://www.svms.org/software.html).

Answer (score 8):

I've used SVMLight before and found it to be very stable and fast. I had a good experience using it and would recommend it.

However, I think there is probably less documentation on SVMLight than libSVM; just the papers by Thorsten Joachims and the comments in the source code. I didn't find the source too hard to follow in general, but you need to read the papers beforehand to understand the background. It's also written in pure C, not C++, if that matters to you.

As for 'new players', the new research is mostly into making the SVM optimisation algorithms more efficient. For example, using stochastic gradient descent as in [svmsgd](http://leon.bottou.org/projects/sgd) and [pegasos](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/code/index.html). I haven't looked at the implementations of these algorithms, but it's research code so I wouldn't expect that they are particularly easy to follow, if that's your primary concern.

Answer (score 5):

[Here's another monster list](http://www.support-vector-machines.org/SVM_soft.html) of SVM packages, libraries and SVM applications.

Answer (score 2):

the best way to get started is to read the libsvm guide provided in the website, also, a good starting video tutorial on how to install libsvm, and do ur first trainig/classification task can be found here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gePWtNAQcK8
good luck with that, i am also just starting it these days, pretty good results that i got, but still tuning it.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [dlib](http://dlib.net/ml.html), which is quiet complete.

> In particular, there are algorithms for performing classification, regression, clustering, sequence labeling, anomaly detection, and feature ranking, as well as algorithms for doing more specialized computations.

Answer (score 0):

[shark](http://shark-project.sourceforge.net)

SHARK is a modular C++ library for the design and optimization of adaptive systems. It provides methods for linear and nonlinear optimization, in particular evolutionary and gradient-based algorithms, kernel-based learning algorithms and neural networks, and various other machine learning techniques. SHARK serves as a toolbox to support real world applications as well as research in different domains of computational intelligence and machine learning. The sources are compatible with the following platforms: Windows, Solaris, MacOS X, and Linux.