# Is it possible to use the chi-squared kernel for an SVM in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, svm

I want to use an SVM with the chi-squared kernel for an application I am writing,  but it doesn't appear obvious how I can apply this.

I define the kernel as `K(x_i, x_j) = exp( -1/A * D(x_i, x_j))`, where `A` is a scaling parameter I can choose, and `D(x_i, x_j)` is the chi-squared distance between them.

How can this be done?  It is a commonly used kernel in the computer vision literature, so it would be surprising if it was not possible.

Comment: Note really sure what you are after..
Is this in the right direction?
http://scikit-learn.org/0.11/modules/kernel_approximation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an option for chi-squared or an custom kernel in opencv.

So one option is to use a different SVM Library.

[This](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~smaji/projects/fiksvm/) is a modification of LIBSVM which supports an chi-squared kernel (a different one) and also precomputed kernels. But its targeted for the use with Matlab. So I am not sure how much it takes to make it work with C++.

Another option could be to use the linear SVM and [transform](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/homkermap.html) your data to approximate the chi-squared kernel, if you want to stick to the opencv svm.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752402/build-a-custom-svm-kernel-matrix-with-opencv) might also give you some more hints.

Answer (score 2):

There is an implementation in OpenCV 3.0.0.0dev. See the link for details.

http://docs.opencv.org/master/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html

New Link:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html