# C++ support vector machine (SVM) template libraries?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, classification, svm

I have a dataset from custom abstract objects and a custom distance function. Is there any good SVM libraries that allows me to train on my custom objects (not 2d points) and my custom distance function?

I searched the answers in [this similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710660/know-any-good-c-support-vector-machine-svm-libraries), but none of them allows me to use custom objects and distance functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first.

SVM **does not work on distance functions**, it only accepts **dot products**. So your distance function (actually similarity, but usually 1-distance is similarity) has to:

- be symmetric `s(a,b)=s(b,a)`
- be positive definite `s(a,a)>=0, s(a,a)=0 <=> a=0`
- be linear in first argument `s(ka, b) = k s(a,b)` and `s(a+b,c) = s(a,c) + s(b,c)`

This can be tricky to check, as you actually ask "is there a function from my objects to some vector space, phi such that `s(phi(x), phi(y))`" is a dot-product, thus leading to definition of so called **kernel**, `K(x,y)=s(phi(x), phi(y))`. If your objects are themselves elements of vector space, then sometimes it is enough to put `phi(x)=x` thus `K=s`, but it is not true in general.

Once you have this kind of similarity nearly any SVM library (for example `libSVM`) works with providing **Gram matrix**. Which is simply defined as

```
G_ij = K(x_i, x_j)
```

Thus requiring `O(N^2)` memory and time. Consequently it does not matter what are your objects, as SVM only works on **pairwise dot-products**, nothing more.

If you look appropriate mathematical tools to show this property, what can be done is to look for **kernel learning from similarity**. These methods are able to create valid kernel which behaves similarly to your similarity.

Comment: Thanks. Actually my "objects" are samples (each of them is a set of sample values), and my "distance function" is a similarity metric between two sets of samples, thus, it is symmetric and positive definite, but i'm not sure about linearity in first argument because I can't define addition and multiplication operations.

Comment: Linearity is the most difficult part. What you can do is try to check empiricaly. Create Matrix of all pairwise similarities and check if it is a PSD Matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the following:

- [MLPack](https://www.mlpack.org/): a lightweight library that provides lots of functionality.
- [DLib](http://dlib.net/): a very popular toolkit that is used both in industry and academia.

Apart from these, you can also use Python packages, but import them from C++.